# Why does Steam cost $ 0.00?

Tags: installation, software-center, steam

When I try to buy it, the Software Centre just redirects me to the "Ubuntu Software Centre Terms of Service".

[image: Steam in the Ubuntu Software Centre]

What should I do?

```
OS: Xubuntu 12.04 LTS (TR Language and Time Zone)
```

Comment: new pic: http://i43.tinypic.com/n3nzt.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to scroll down and accept the Terms of Service. You may need to create an account with Ubuntu to install this application. The "price" of $0.00 is so Steam can track how many people are using the program. You can also download it from [the Steam website](http://store.steampowered.com/).